# MongoDB - aggregate multiple fields in one query

Tags: mongodb

I'm developing a monitoring system for our company's production system. This means the nature of the data I'll be storing is time-series. I picked MongoDB for this purpose, after reviewing several other databases.
Events from the production system will arrive all the time, but I intend to store events in a 10-minute interval document. Eventually, documents in the collection will look like this:

```
{
   _id: '04/25/2015 13:00',
   event1_count : 130,
   event2_count : 50,
   event3_count : 200
},

{
    _id: '04/25/2015 13:10',
    event1_count : 230,
    event2_count : 20,
    event3_count : 400
}
```

The document   `_id: '04/25/2015 13:00'` simply means it has all the events the arrived between 04/25/2015 13:00 and 04/25/2015 13:10.

Ultimately, I'll want different reports to run on the data. For example - count of events within the last 20 minutes.
The result I would like to get for event count in last 20 minute is:

```
{
event1_count : 360,
event2_count : 70,
event3_count : 600
}
```

My question - is there a way to aggregate multiple fields from different documents, in one query?

BTW - it's important for me to keep the data at a 10 minute interval, because other reports will need that time resolution.

Comment: In my question you can see 2 documents. Each document has several fields - event1_count, event2_count etc. I'd like to sum event_count1 from both documents, and the same goes for event_count2. So the result should be sum of event_count1, sum of event_count2 and so on. I'm looking for a way to do that in the one query, assuming I'll have plenty of other events, and not only 3 as in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's indeed possible. Suppose your collection will be storing the documents in the above-mentioned structure, you could modify the structure by adding another field say `date` which stores the _id as an ISODate, rather than the string timestamp so that you can do the aggregation using **[Date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)**. To do the conversion, you can use mongo's [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) cursor method to do an atomic update with the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) operator:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function (doc){
    var dateObject = new Date(doc._id);    
    db.collection.update({_id: doc._id}, { $set: { date: dateObject } });               
});
```

The above will create an extra field `date` in your documents that contains an ISODate object representation of the `_id` string.

Suppose you now have the following sample documents in your collection after the update above:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : "04/25/2015 13:00",
    "event1_count" : 130,
    "event2_count" : 50,
    "event3_count" : 200,
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-25T13:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "04/25/2015 13:10",
    "event1_count" : 230,
    "event2_count" : 20,
    "event3_count" : 400,
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-25T13:10:00.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "04/25/2015 13:20",
    "event1_count" : 240,
    "event2_count" : 30,
    "event3_count" : 350,
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-25T13:20:00.000Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "04/25/2015 13:30",
    "event1_count" : 180,
    "event2_count" : 60,
    "event3_count" : 500,
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-25T13:30:00.000Z")
}
```

The following aggregation pipeline will give you the desired result, based on the 20 minute interval:

```
var interval = 20,
    pipeline = [
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "year": { "$year": "$date" },
                "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$date" },
                "interval": {
                    "$subtract": [ 
                        { "$minute": "$date" },
                        { "$mod": [{ "$minute": "$date" }, interval ] }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "event1_count": { "$sum": "$event1_count" },
            "event2_count": { "$sum": "$event2_count" },
            "event3_count": { "$sum": "$event3_count" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "event1_count": 1,
            "event2_count": 1,
            "event3_count": 1
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "event1_count" : 420,
            "event2_count" : 90,
            "event3_count" : 850
        }, 
        {
            "event1_count" : 360,
            "event2_count" : 70,
            "event3_count" : 600
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: @assafm No worries :-)